# Sparrow/Turner/Norrington fight in the "wheel" - does it represents some kind of "turning plot"?

Tags: pirates-of-the-caribbean, dead-mans-chest

I mean, there are three characters with completely different motivations, but all their motivations comes to the chest at some point. The movie plot is truly turning hard around it. So the fight eventually comes into the wheel and they are turning in it. And at certain moment there is a perspective when it is the world turning around the wheel.

I wonder, is it just another stunt episode? Or did the movie creators intentionally make the visualized metaphor for what they did entangle in the movie? Are there any mentions regarding to that?

Comment: I bet that when people were watching that scene no one was thinking about **metaphor** part. There is so fun in that you stop thinking and start laughing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good way to view it as metaphor, however it's just coincidence. It is a normal fight sequence, if you remember, most of the fight stunts involving 'Jack Sparrow' are the same including props. Having a wheel provides a way to show 3 persons fighting individually.